# How to use a Box<String> as a lookup key for a hashmap with &str keys?

Tags: string, types, rust, reference, hashmap

My hashmap keys are expected to be of type `&str`, in particular `&'static str`, and I've received an owned `Box<String>`.
How do I search my string against my hashmap?

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, u32> = HashMap::new();
    let static_string = "a";
    map.insert(static_string, 5);

    let owned_boxed_string = Box::new(String::from("a"));

    map.get(owned_boxed_string); // mismatched type (ok)
    map.get(*owned_boxed_string); // mismatched type (ok)
    map.get(&*owned_boxed_string); // trait bound not satisfied (?)
}
```

Comment: `Box<String>` is unusual; you might want to use `Box<str>` instead (`let owned_boxed_str = String::from("a").into_boxed_str();`) You lose the "growableness" but you also lose one pointer's worth of indirection. It also makes `&*` work with no other changes.

Comment: @trentcl I think I understand what you mean. The reason is that the `String` is of unkown size and has been collected from a `TcpStream` in another thread. It has been `Box`ed not be `memcpy`ed around too often down `mpsc::channel`s, so I receive it as-is. Does `Box<str>` mean that the size of `str` must be statically known? Or is it just "a boxed slice of string"?

Comment: `str` is always dynamically sized, it's like `[u8]` (slices are also dynamically sized). `Box<str>` is basically the same as `String` except it only stores a pointer and length whereas `String` stores a capacity. `Box<String>` stores a pointer to a `String`, so if you need to access the length of the string you have to follow one pointer and if you need to access the bytes of the string you have to follow two pointers. But as far as `memcpy`ing goes, there's no real difference between `Box<str>`, `Box<String>` and plain `String`, so maybe you shoulg not be using the `Box` at all.

Comment: By "no real difference" I mean: if you move a `String` you just copy the pointer, not the bytes. If you clone a `String` you copy the bytes and create a new pointer. This is essentially the same for `Box<String>`, except `Box<String>` does more work when you clone it. `Box<str>` is a bit of an optimization on top of `String` when you don't intend to grow the allocation.

Comment: @trentctl Well, I've learned something! Non-growable strings not `memcpy`ied around when shared among threads are actually what I'm after. I'll try to trade my `Box<String>`s for `Box<str>` then. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of [`HashMap::get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get):

```
pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V> where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

In your code, `K` is `&'static str` and `Q` is deduced from each of the calls to `get`. In plain English, `get()` takes a reference to a type `Q` such that `&'static str` implements `Borrow<Q>`.

The rationale is that usually you will store keys of type `String` or the like, and you will search using values of type `&str`. And naturally `String` implements `Borrow<str>` so you can do that.

In your case, your key is not `String` but `&'static str`... Take a look at the documentation for [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) and look for what kind of `Borrow<Q>` is implemented by `&'static str`. I can only see these two blanket implementations:

```
impl<'_, T: ?Sized> Borrow<T> for &'_ T
impl<T: ?Sized> Borrow<T> for T
```

The first one states that if your map keys are references to some type `&K` you can call `get(k: &K)`. The second one says that if your key is `K` you can call `get(k: &K)`.

So for your particular case of `&'static str` they are realized as:

```
impl Borrow<str> for &'static str
impl Borrow<&'static str> for &'static str
```

From that you can deduce that your function is either `get(k: &str)` or `get(k: &&str)`. Here the easiest choice is the first one.

Now, you may think that your last line (`map.get(&*owned_boxed_string);`) should work, because that value is of type `&str`, but it actually is not, it is of type `&String`. If `HashMap::get()` received a `&str` it would compile fine, but taking a `Borrow<Q>`, the compiler gets all confused and fails.

**TL; DR;**: Add a type cast or a temporary typed variable:

```
map.get(&*owned_boxed_string as &str);  //ok
map.get(&owned_boxed_string as &str);   //also ok

let s: &str = &*owned_boxed_string;
map.get(s);
let s: &str = &owned_boxed_string;
map.get(s);
```

Although an easier solution (thanks to @harmic for the comment below) is to use `String::as_str()` that will take care of as many derefs as required and just return the necessary `&str`:

```
map.get(owned_boxed_string.as_str());
```

Comment: Another possible solution: `map.get(&owned_boxed_string.as_str());`

Comment: @harmic: Of course! I always forget `as_str()` and `as_slice()`. Often they are the easiest ones.

Comment: `map.get(&**owned_boxed_string);` would be the usual way I've seen it.

Comment: @Shepmaster Well, cheers to y'all. I've learned a lot today :) Any pros/cons to `.as_str()` *vs.* `as &str` *vs.* `&**`?

Comment: @iago-lito: The pro of `as_str()` is that it always returns a `&str` no matter how many indirections are needed, it would just work with a `String`, a `&String`, a `&Box<String>`, a `std::cell::Ref<Box<String>>`, and so on... With the other you have to count how many `*` to use.

Comment: Okay, I get it :) What about `as &str`? Is it just different syntax for the same behaviour as `.as_str()`?

Comment: @iago-lito: No, `as T` is a cast. If the expression is convertible to `T` then it will be force that conversion. For example a `&String` is convertible to `&str` (because of the `Deref` magic). However `as_str()` is a true function, that is [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/string.rs.html#767) using the same conversion, so the result is identical.